# Recover lost progress in Minecraft Pocket Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On Minecraft Pocket Edition, my progress on the app just vanished. Is there a way to recover it? I hooked my phone up to my computer recently, and it synced.

Comment: what kind of phone

Comment: In some cases, restarting your device will bring your progress back. Have you tried that?